# (consolibyte) quickbooks-php devkit, how to add company name?

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to add company name when I add a new customer, anyone can help?
By the way, where is the documentation for quickboos-php devkit , I can't find it as well.
The below is the code:

```
    $CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();
    //add basic info
    $Customer = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Customer();
    $Customer->setTitle($title);
    $Customer->setGivenName($given_name);
    $Customer->setMiddleName($middel_name);
    $Customer->setFamilyName($family_name);
    $Customer->setDisplayName($display_name);

    // Phone #
    $PrimaryPhone = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PrimaryPhone();
    $PrimaryPhone->setFreeFormNumber($primary_phone);
    $Customer->setPrimaryPhone($PrimaryPhone);

    // Mobile #
    $Mobile = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Mobile();
    $Mobile->setFreeFormNumber($mobile);
    $Customer->setMobile($Mobile);

    // Bill address
    $BillAddr = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_BillAddr();
    $BillAddr->setLine1($bill_address);
    $BillAddr->setCity($bill_city);
    $BillAddr->setCountrySubDivisionCode($bill_state);
    $BillAddr->setCountry($bill_country);
    $BillAddr->setPostalCode($bill_zip_code);
    $Customer->setBillAddr($BillAddr);

    // Shipping address
    $ShipAddr = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_ShipAddr();
    $ShipAddr->setLine1($address_1);
    $ShipAddr->setLine2($address_2);
    $ShipAddr->setCity($city);
    $ShipAddr->setCountrySubDivisionCode($province);
    $ShipAddr->setCountry($country);
    $ShipAddr->setPostalCode($postal_code);
    $Customer->setShipAddr($ShipAddr);

    $customer_id = $CustomerService->add($Context, $realm, $Customer);
```

Comment: Did you look at the project Github? It has all the links to the documentation: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php -- also, why would you add a company name to a customer? I'm pretty sure companies and customers are different entities.

Comment: QuickBooks has no concept of a separate "company" entity really. Your customer may be a company, or it may be an individual, depending on if you're B2B or B2C. Customers do indeed have a Company Name field in QuickBooks.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The list of available fields for `Customer` objects is on Intuit's website:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/customer

You're probably looking for:

`CompanyName:
optional
String, maximum of 50 chars, filterable, sortable, default is null 
The name of the company associated with the person or organization.`

Unsurprisingly, there's a couple of corresponding methods:

```
$Customer->setCompanyName($v);
$v = $Customer->getCompanyName();
```